# Cannot pass variable from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this simple script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php 

    $latitude = 53.071174;
    $longitude = 28.296536;
?>

</head>
<body>

<script>

    var jsLatitude = <?php echo json_encode($latitude); ?>;
    var jsLongitude = <?php echo json_encode($longitude); ?>;
    alert(jsLatitude);
    alert(jsLongitude);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it gives me a **Syntax error** at this line

```
var jsLatitude = <?php echo json_encode($latitude); ?>;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: json_encode is a string. You need to put in single quotes.

Comment: Why do you use `json_encode()`? You can directly `echo` the value since it is a float: `var jsLatitude = <?php echo $latitude; ?>;`

Comment: @MarkusZeller if I use the single quotes, i don't get the value of the PHP variable, I'll get '<?php echo json_encode($latitude); ?>' as a string

Comment: @HarunYilmaz the issue remains, as I get a Syntax error at the line **15**, on **<?php**

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You've a HTML file, not a PHP file?

Comment: @Teemu yes, the file is a .html

Comment: @HarunYilmaz sorry, I don't have anymore details, the code shown in the HTML source is 'SCRIPT1002: SCRIPT1002: Syntax error' at 'script.html (15,20)'

Comment: PHP is run only in PHP files, you've to save the file with php extension.

Comment: @Teemu tryied, but the issue still remains

Comment: You've to to load that new PHP file to the browser too, change the link or the address on the address bar.

Comment: HTML can not process anything. You need to use PHP.

Comment: If the file is loaded from the correct URL, you've to check PHP is correctly installed and running on your server ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as suggested by @Markus Zeller and @Teemu it was just the extension of the file (I was working on an HTML file instead of a PHP) and I was working on my personal PC.
Changing the extension and uploading the script to a server with PHP installed solded the problem.